# Which attribute to get XY from a contentMouseover event?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am using the contentMouseover event on my stage to show the user the XY-value of the pointer position.
What I observed is that different browsers have different attributes of the event object.
On Opera the event object has x,y attributes, on Firefox they are unknown.
My question now: How can I get the x and y value where the event occurred on all browsers?
Which attribute is to be used?

Comment: You can use a framework like jQuery. It has crossbrowser wrappers for stuff like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your contentMouseover event handler you can get the stage mouseX/mouseY with stage.getMousePosition:

```
var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
var mouseX=pos.x;
var mouseY=pos.y;
```